# Concourse CI Windows Worker

Tags: concourse

I'm trying to setup a Concourse CI environment with a *Windows 7* worker.

I have one machine under *Ubuntu Server (16.04)* hosting my TSA server and one worker (for the support of git resources), and a second one under *Windows 7* hosting a worker.

Everything seems to work fine as:

- I can login into the web ui
- the `fly -t my_concourseci workers` command returns :

  ```
  name      containers  platform  tags  team  state    version
  ubuntu    1           linux     none  none  running  1.1
  windows7  0           windows   none  none  running  1.1
  ```
- the `fly -t my_concourseci execute -c test.yml` command returns:

  ```
  executing build 146
  initializing
  running echo Hello World!
  Hello World!
  ```

  with the following content in *test.yml* file:

  ```
  platform: windows

  run:
    path: echo
    args: [ "Hello World!" ]
  ```

Nevertheless when I add an input to my task:

```
    platform: windows

    > inputs:
    >  - name: concourse

    run:
      path: echo
      args: [ "Hello World!" ]
```

I get the following error:

```
executing build 148
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 5698k    0 5698k    0     0  1948k      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- 1949k
initializing
failed to stream in to volume
errored
```

If I look at the windows worker log I got this error that comes up:

```
{"timestamp":"1500642862.643555164",
"source":"baggageclaim",
"message":"baggageclaim.api.volume-server.stream-in.bad-stream-payload",
"log_level":1,
"data":{"error":"tar extract failed (exit status 2). output: \"\\ngzip: stdin: not in gzip format\\n/usr/bin/tar: Child returned status 1\\n/usr/bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now\\n\"",
"session":"2.1.8730",
 "volume":"15bf1fc6-0727-4962-6c84-18446e54ab96"}
}
```

Any ideas about what can cause a `not in gzip format` error ? Knowing that if I run the exact same task on a linux platform every works fine.

```
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: busybox}

inputs:
 - name: concourse


run:
  path: echo
  args: [ "Hello World!" ]
----- STDOUT
executing build 149
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 5699k    0 5699k    0     0  1917k      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- 1918k
initializing
Pulling busybox@sha256:2605a2c4875ce5eb27a9f7403263190cd1af31e48a2044d400320548356251c4...
sha256:2605a2c4875ce5eb27a9f7403263190cd1af31e48a2044d400320548356251c4: Pulling from library/busybox
9e87eff13613: Pulling fs layer
9e87eff13613: Verifying Checksum
9e87eff13613: Download complete
9e87eff13613: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:2605a2c4875ce5eb27a9f7403263190cd1af31e48a2044d400320548356251c4
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox@sha256:2605a2c4875ce5eb27a9f7403263190cd1af31e48a2044d400320548356251c4

Successfully pulled busybox@sha256:2605a2c4875ce5eb27a9f7403263190cd1af31e48a2044d400320548356251c4.

running echo Hello World!
succeeded
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the execute command you're running after you add the input to the job? Are you providing an input to `execute` and is it a folder?

Comment: @ErginBabani I run 'fly -t my_concourse execute -c test.yml', and yes my input is a folder. Would you suggest that inputs have to be compressed in zip format before I execute my fly command ?

Comment: You don't have to zip anything, `fly` is doing this behind the scenes. This looks like a setup issue with the windows worker. Are you hosting the `concourse web` on Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: @JTArchie the `concourse web` is hosted on Ubuntu. I guess you are right about the windows worker issue but I can't figure out the problem here.

Comment: Are you actually providing an `input` for the `concourse` input when you run `fly execute`? It should look something like `fly execute -c task.yml -i concourse=directory_path`.

Comment: How is the resource concourse defined?  I've been having great luck on win10 and will try to help if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Launch powershell as Administrator, and run the concourse_worker.exe from there. That worked for me.

I am running a Windows Server 2016 Base on AWS based on this AMI ami-e1876a98

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, it helps me solve my problem.

I were starting my `concourse worker` within a *MSYS 1.0* environment. The thing is that *MSYS* contains `tar` and `gunzip` binaries within the `$PATH`. When I started `concourse worker` inside a *Power Shell* or *cmd.exe* without any *MSYS* unix-like binaries in the `$PATH` it worked like a charm !

Note: Be sure to have no *MSYS* binaries in the `$PATH` Windows environment variable for this to work, especially check that Git-Bash environment tools are not added to your windows $PATH environment variable.

Thanks again.